# Selenium - unable to determine error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 92, Size: 92

Tags: java, selenium

I understand this question has been asked couple of times but I have tried most of solutions and finally posting... if missed any please direct me thanks.

I am trying to go a page and grab all the links in a tag ('a') and click on each displayed link, for some reason I am getting

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 92, Size: 92

```
 public static void clickOnEachLinkOnAPage(String tagName, String homePageTitle) {

    int numberOfElementsFound = getNumberOfElementsFound(By.tagName(tagName));
    System.out.println(numberOfElementsFound);
    for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfElementsFound; pos++) {

        if (getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).isDisplayed()) {
            String linkText = getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).getText().trim();
            String url = getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).getAttribute("href");
        if (linkText.length()!=0) {
                getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).click();
                String newWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
                Generic.handleMultipleWindows(newWindow);
                String pageTitle =  driver.getTitle();
                linkText = StringUtils.abbreviate(linkText, 10);
                System.out.println(pos +","+linkText+","+url+","+pageTitle);
               // System.out.println(linkText+","+url+","+pageTitle);
                closeAllOtherWindows(newWindow );
            System.out.println("number of elements"+numberOfElementsFound);
                if(!pageTitle.equals(homePageTitle)) {
                    driver.navigate().back();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



public static int getNumberOfElementsFound(By by) {
    return driver.findElements(by).size();
}


public static WebElement getElementWithIndex(By by, int pos) {
    return driver.findElements(by).get(pos);
}

   public static boolean closeAllOtherWindows(String openWindowHandle) {
    Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String currentWindowHandle : allWindowHandles) {
        if (!currentWindowHandle.equals(openWindowHandle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(currentWindowHandle);
            driver.close();
        }
    }

    driver.switchTo().window(openWindowHandle);
    if (driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

    public static void handleMultipleWindows(String windowTitle) {
    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for (String window : windows) {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        if (driver.getTitle().contains(windowTitle)) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Error I am getting

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 92, Size: 92

Comment: You're accessing the index 92 with an array of the size 92. Index 92 doesn't exist because arrays are zero based

Comment: Which line does cause this error? I guess the root cause is some links are removed after page loaded.

Comment: When I run in debug mode -- my test is failing at if (getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).isDisplayed()) {

Comment: @Andrew, thanks but my problem is - in a page I found 98 elements but error is showing java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 92, Size: 92 - doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: @user790049 Inside the method `getElementWithIndex`, could you print this `driver.findElements(by).size();` before return?

Comment: @Buaban, thanks, yes it seems i found the problem, i have printed and found few output line are showing 98 and few are showing 92, when it reached 93 logically it is entering into the loop but the page where I am in trying to check i.e. if (getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).isDisplayed()) has got only 92 and throws this error... I hope my analysis is correct - correct me if I am wrong.. trying to fix but need to work on... hopefully I will find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Provide an MCVE. In the process of reducing the code you will likely find the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my code as below and works fine... Thank you all. I have changed a little bit to make it work.

```
public static void clickOnEachLinkOnAPage(String tagName, String homePageTitle) {

    int numberOfElementsFound = getNumberOfElementsFound(By.tagName(tagName));
    // System.out.println(numberOfElementsFound);
    String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfElementsFound; pos++) {
        String linkText = getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).getText().trim();
        if (linkText.length() != 0) {
            String url = getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).getAttribute("href");
            getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).click();
            String newWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
            Generic.handleMultipleWindows(newWindow);
            String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();
            linkText = StringUtils.abbreviate(linkText, 10);
            //   System.out.println(pos +","+linkText+","+url+","+pageTitle);
            System.out.println(linkText + "," + url + "," + pageTitle);
            closeAllOtherWindows(newWindow);
            Generic.handleMultipleWindows(currentWindow);
            String pageTitleCurrent = driver.getTitle();
            if (!pageTitleCurrent.equals(homePageTitle)) {
                driver.navigate().back();
            }
        }
    }
}
```